# How to approach and fix npm security issue(s) semver vulnerable to Regular Expression Denial of Service

Tags: reactjs, npm, dependencies, package.json

In my azure pipeline I get an error:

> semver  <7.5.2 Severity: moderate semver vulnerable to Regular
> Expression Denial of Service -
> https://github.com/advisories/GHSA-c2qf-rxjj-qqgw

When I add `semver` to my resolutions in `package.json`:

```
"resolutions": {
    "semver": "7.5.2"
  }
```

then I get another error in pipeline:

```
npm ERR! path /my-path-to/node_modules/semver/bin/semver
npm ERR! errno -2
npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, chmod '/my-path-to/node_modules/semver/bin/semver'
npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm ERR! enoent
```

Why do I have to do? I know I have to update packages but I need to add the feature first.

When I do npm `outdated` I get a big list:

```
Package                                           Current          Wanted          Latest  Location                                                Depended by
@apollo/client                                     3.3.19          3.7.16          3.7.16  node_modules/@apollo/client                             myrepo
@babel/cli                                         7.14.3          7.22.5          7.22.5  node_modules/@babel/cli                                 myrepo
@babel/core                                        7.14.3          7.22.5          7.22.5  node_modules/@babel/core                                myrepo
@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties            7.13.0          7.18.6          7.18.6  node_modules/@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties    myrepo
@babel/plugin-proposal-object-rest-spread          7.14.2          7.20.7          7.20.7  node_modules/@babel/plugin-proposal-object-rest-spread  myrepo
@babel/plugin-proposal-optional-chaining           7.14.2          7.21.0          7.21.0  node_modules/@babel/plugin-proposal-optional-chaining   myrepo
@babel/plugin-transform-modules-commonjs           7.14.0          7.22.5          7.22.5  node_modules/@babel/plugin-transform-modules-commonjs   myrepo
@babel/plugin-transform-runtime                    7.14.3          7.22.5          7.22.5  node_modules/@babel/plugin-transform-runtime            myrepo
@babel/preset-env                                  7.14.2          7.22.5          7.22.5  node_modules/@babel/preset-env                          myrepo
@babel/preset-flow                                7.13.13          7.22.5          7.22.5  node_modules/@babel/preset-flow                         myrepo
@babel/preset-react                               7.13.13          7.22.5          7.22.5  node_modules/@babel/preset-react                        myrepo
@babel/preset-typescript                           7.13.0          7.22.5          7.22.5  node_modules/@babel/preset-typescript                   myrepo
@babel/register                                   7.13.16          7.22.5          7.22.5  node_modules/@babel/register                            myrepo
@brainhubeu/react-carousel                        1.19.26         1.19.26           2.0.4  node_modules/@brainhubeu/react-carousel                 myrepo
@elastic/ecs-pino-format                            0.1.0           0.1.0           1.3.0  node_modules/@elastic/ecs-pino-format                   myrepo
@emotion/babel-plugin                              11.3.0         11.11.0         11.11.0  node_modules/@emotion/babel-plugin                      myrepo
@emotion/babel-preset-css-prop                     11.2.0         11.11.0         11.11.0  node_modules/@emotion/babel-preset-css-prop             myrepo
@emotion/jest                                      11.9.1         11.11.0         11.11.0  node_modules/@emotion/jest                              myrepo
@emotion/react                                     11.4.0         11.11.1         11.11.1  node_modules/@emotion/react                             myrepo
@emotion/styled                                    11.3.0         11.11.0         11.11.0  node_modules/@emotion/styled                            myrepo
@godaddy/terminus                                   4.8.0          4.12.0          4.12.0  node_modules/@godaddy/terminus                          myrepo
@graphql-codegen/cli                                2.6.2          2.16.5           4.0.1  node_modules/@graphql-codegen/cli                       myrepo
@graphql-codegen/fragment-matcher                  1.17.8          1.17.8           5.0.0  node_modules/@graphql-codegen/fragment-matcher          myrepo
@graphql-codegen/typescript                         2.4.8           2.8.8           4.0.1  node_modules/@graphql-codegen/typescript                myrepo
@loadable/babel-plugin                             5.13.2          5.15.3          5.15.3  node_modules/@loadable/babel-plugin                     myrepo
@loadable/component                                5.15.0          5.15.3          5.15.3  node_modules/@loadable/component                        myrepo
@loadable/server                                   5.15.0          5.15.3          5.15.3  node_modules/@loadable/server                           myrepo
@loadable/webpack-plugin                           5.15.0          5.15.2          5.15.2  node_modules/@loadable/webpack-plugin                   myrepo
@material-ui/core                                  4.11.4          4.12.4          4.12.4  node_modules/@material-ui/core                          myrepo
@material-ui/lab                           4.0.0-alpha.60  4.0.0-alpha.61  4.0.0-alpha.61  node_modules/@material-ui/lab                           myrepo
@material-ui/styles                                4.11.4          4.11.5          4.11.5  node_modules/@material-ui/styles                        myrepo
@my-reop/conventional-changelog                       2.1.0           2.1.0           2.2.0  node_modules/@my-repo/conventional-changelog              myrepo
@storybook/addon-actions                            6.3.4          6.5.16          7.0.23  node_modules/@storybook/addon-actions                   myrepo
@storybook/addon-essentials                         6.3.4          6.5.16          7.0.23  node_modules/@storybook/addon-essentials                myrepo
@storybook/addon-links                              6.3.4          6.5.16          7.0.23  node_modules/@storybook/addon-links                     myrepo
@storybook/react                                   6.4.22          6.5.16          7.0.23  node_modules/@storybook/react                           myrepo
@svgr/webpack                                       4.3.3           4.3.3           8.0.1  node_modules/@svgr/webpack                              myrepo
@testing-library/jest-dom                          5.12.0          5.16.5          5.16.5  node_modules/@testing-library/jest-dom                  myrepo
@testing-library/react                              9.5.0           9.5.0          14.0.0  node_modules/@testing-library/react                     myrepo
@types/body-parser                                 1.19.0          1.19.2          1.19.2  node_modules/@types/body-parser                         myrepo
@types/brainhubeu__react-carousel                  1.15.0          1.15.0           2.0.5  node_modules/@types/brainhubeu__react-carousel          myrepo
@types/cors                                        2.8.10          2.8.13          2.8.13  node_modules/@types/cors                                myrepo
@types/dotenv                                       6.1.1           6.1.1           8.2.0  node_modules/@types/dotenv                              myrepo
@types/express                                    4.17.13         4.17.17         4.17.17  node_modules/@types/express                             myrepo
@types/http-errors                                  1.8.0           1.8.2           2.0.1  node_modules/@types/http-errors                         myrepo
@types/isomorphic-fetch                            0.0.35          0.0.35          0.0.36  node_modules/@types/isomorphic-fetch                    myrepo
@types/jest                                        27.0.0          27.5.2          29.5.2  node_modules/@types/jest                                myrepo
@types/loadable__component                         5.13.3          5.13.4          5.13.4  node_modules/@types/loadable__component                 myrepo
@types/loadable__server                            5.12.5          5.12.6          5.12.6  node_modules/@types/loadable__server                    myrepo
@types/lodash                                    4.14.169        4.14.195        4.14.195  node_modules/@types/lodash                              myrepo
@types/node                                      12.20.13        12.20.55          20.3.1  node_modules/@types/node                                myrepo
@types/pino                                         6.3.8          6.3.12           7.0.5  node_modules/@types/pino                                myrepo
@types/pino-http                                    5.4.1           5.8.1           5.8.1  node_modules/@types/pino-http                           myrepo
@types/react                                       17.0.6         17.0.62         18.2.13  node_modules/@types/react                               myrepo
@types/react-dom                                   17.0.5         17.0.20          18.2.6  node_modules/@types/react-dom                           myrepo
@types/react-lazyload                               3.1.0           3.2.0           3.2.0  node_modules/@types/react-lazyload                      myrepo
@types/react-router                                5.1.14          5.1.20          5.1.20  node_modules/@types/react-router                        myrepo
@types/react-router-config                          5.0.2           5.0.7           5.0.7  node_modules/@types/react-router-config                 myrepo
@types/recompose                                   0.30.7         0.30.10         0.30.10  node_modules/@types/recompose                           myrepo
@types/serialize-javascript                         5.0.1           5.0.2           5.0.2  node_modules/@types/serialize-javascript                myrepo
@types/storybook__react                             4.0.2           4.0.2           5.2.1  node_modules/@types/storybook__react                    myrepo
@types/storybook-addon-jsx                          5.4.3           5.4.3           7.0.4  node_modules/@types/storybook-addon-jsx                 myrepo
@types/webpack-env                                 1.16.0          1.18.1          1.18.1  node_modules/@types/webpack-env                         myrepo
@types/yup                                        0.26.37         0.26.37          0.32.0  node_modules/@types/yup                                 myrepo
@typescript-eslint/parser                          2.34.0          2.34.0          5.60.0  node_modules/@typescript-eslint/parser                  myrepo
babel-jest                                         25.5.1          25.5.1          29.5.0  node_modules/babel-jest                                 myrepo
babel-loader                                        8.2.2           8.3.0           9.1.2  node_modules/babel-loader                               myrepo
babel-plugin-macros                                 2.8.0           2.8.0           3.1.0  node_modules/babel-plugin-macros                        myrepo
babel-plugin-named-asset-import                     0.3.7           0.3.8           0.3.8  node_modules/babel-plugin-named-asset-import            myrepo
body-parser                                        1.20.0          1.20.2          1.20.2  node_modules/body-parser                                myrepo
chalk                                               2.4.2           2.4.2           5.2.0  node_modules/chalk                                      myrepo
core-js                                            3.12.1          3.31.0          3.31.0  node_modules/core-js                                    myrepo
cross-env                                           5.2.1           5.2.1           7.0.3  node_modules/cross-env                                  myrepo
crypto-hash                                         1.3.0           1.3.0           2.0.1  node_modules/crypto-hash                                myrepo
css-loader                                          3.6.0           3.6.0           6.8.1  node_modules/css-loader                                 myrepo
cypress                                             7.3.0           7.7.0         12.15.0  node_modules/cypress                                    myrepo
cypress-cucumber-preprocessor                       4.1.0           4.3.1           4.3.1  node_modules/cypress-cucumber-preprocessor              myrepo
date-fns                                           2.21.3          2.30.0          2.30.0  node_modules/date-fns                                   myrepo
dotenv                                              8.6.0           8.6.0          16.3.1  node_modules/dotenv                                     myrepo
eslint-loader                                       3.0.4           3.0.4           4.0.2  node_modules/eslint-loader                              myrepo
express                                            4.18.1          4.18.2          4.18.2  node_modules/express                                    myrepo
file-loader                                         4.3.0           4.3.0           6.2.0  node_modules/file-loader                                myrepo
formik                                              2.2.7           2.4.2           2.4.2  node_modules/formik                                     myrepo
graphql                                            14.7.0          14.7.0          16.7.1  node_modules/graphql                                    myrepo
history                                            4.10.1          4.10.1           5.3.0  node_modules/history                                    myrepo
hpropagate                                          0.0.7           0.0.7           1.0.1  node_modules/hpropagate                                 myrepo
html-react-parser                                  1.4.14          1.4.14           4.0.0  node_modules/html-react-parser                          myrepo
html-webpack-plugin                                 3.2.0           3.2.0           5.5.3  node_modules/html-webpack-plugin                        myrepo
http-errors                                         1.8.0           1.8.1           2.0.0  node_modules/http-errors                                myrepo
husky                                               3.1.0           3.1.0           8.0.3  node_modules/husky                                      myrepo
is-mobile                                           2.2.2           2.2.2           4.0.0  node_modules/is-mobile                                  myrepo
jest                                               25.5.4          25.5.4          29.5.0  node_modules/jest                                       myrepo
jest-junit                                          8.0.0           8.0.0          16.0.0  node_modules/jest-junit                                 myrepo
jsdom                                              15.1.1          15.1.1          22.1.0  node_modules/jsdom                                      myrepo
lint-staged                                         9.5.0           9.5.0          13.2.2  node_modules/lint-staged                                myrepo
mini-css-extract-plugin                             0.8.2           0.8.2           2.7.6  node_modules/mini-css-extract-plugin                    myrepo
nanoid                                              3.2.0           3.3.6           4.0.2  node_modules/nanoid                                     myrepo
nodemon                                             2.0.7          2.0.22          2.0.22  node_modules/nodemon                                    myrepo
pino                                               6.11.3          6.14.0          8.14.1  node_modules/pino                                       myrepo
pino-http                                           5.5.0           5.8.0           8.3.3  node_modules/pino-http                                  myrepo
pino-pretty                                         4.8.0           4.8.0          10.0.0  node_modules/pino-pretty                                myrepo
prettier                                           1.19.1          1.19.1           2.8.8  node_modules/prettier                                   myrepo
puppeteer                                          1.20.0          1.20.0          20.7.3  node_modules/puppeteer                                  myrepo
query-string                                        7.0.0           7.1.3           8.1.0  node_modules/query-string                               myrepo
react                                              17.0.2          17.0.2          18.2.0  node_modules/react                                      myrepo
react-cookie                                        4.0.3           4.1.1           4.1.1  node_modules/react-cookie                               myrepo
react-dev-utils                                    11.0.4          11.0.4          12.0.1  node_modules/react-dev-utils                            myrepo
react-dom                                          17.0.2          17.0.2          18.2.0  node_modules/react-dom                                  myrepo
react-helmet-async                                  1.0.9           1.3.0           1.3.0  node_modules/react-helmet-async                         myrepo
react-router                                        5.2.0           5.3.4          6.13.0  node_modules/react-router                               myrepo
react-router-dom                                    5.2.0           5.3.4          6.13.0  node_modules/react-router-dom                           myrepo
react-twitter-widgets                              1.10.0          1.11.0          1.11.0  node_modules/react-twitter-widgets                      myrepo
regenerator-runtime                                0.13.7         0.13.11         0.13.11  node_modules/regenerator-runtime                        myrepo
rimraf                                              3.0.2           3.0.2           5.0.1  node_modules/rimraf                                     myrepo
serialize-javascript                                6.0.0           6.0.1           6.0.1  node_modules/serialize-javascript                       myrepo
source-map-explorer                                 2.5.2           2.5.3           2.5.3  node_modules/source-map-explorer                        myrepo
start-server-and-test                              1.12.2          1.15.4           2.0.0  node_modules/start-server-and-test                      myrepo
swiper                                              6.8.4           6.8.4           9.4.1  node_modules/swiper                                     myrepo
terser-webpack-plugin                               1.4.5           1.4.5           5.3.9  node_modules/terser-webpack-plugin                      myrepo
typescript                                         3.9.10          3.9.10           5.1.3  node_modules/typescript                                 myrepo
url-loader                                          2.3.0           2.3.0           4.1.1  node_modules/url-loader                                 myrepo
webpack                                            4.46.0          4.46.0          5.88.0  node_modules/webpack                                    myrepo
webpack-cli                                        3.3.12          3.3.12           5.1.4  node_modules/webpack-cli                                myrepo
webpack-dev-server                                 3.11.3          3.11.3          4.15.1  node_modules/webpack-dev-server                         myrepo
webpack-hot-middleware                             2.25.1          2.25.4          2.25.4  node_modules/webpack-hot-middleware                     myrepo
webpack-manifest-plugin                             2.2.0           2.2.0           5.0.0  node_modules/webpack-manifest-plugin                    myrepo
webpack-merge                                       5.8.0           5.9.0           5.9.0  node_modules/webpack-merge                              myrepo
webpack-node-externals                              1.7.2           1.7.2           3.0.0  node_modules/webpack-node-externals                     myrepo
yup                                                0.28.5          0.28.5           1.2.0  node_modules/yup                                        myrepo
```

How do a fix this issue?

Comment: Always ask yourself if those security errors are false positives. See this article ->https://overreacted.io/npm-audit-broken-by-design/

Sadly, I can't give you an answer to your question but check out where semver is used. If it is a dependency from some lint configs, then most likely it is a false positive (this is the case for my project).

Answer (score 27):

Yes semver is having a security vulnerability more about that [here](https://github.com/advisories/GHSA-c2qf-rxjj-qqgw)

This issue has been fixed in semver version `^7.5.3`. For your app to use the said verion you can add the [overrides](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v9/configuring-npm/package-json#overrides) to your package.json.

```
  "overrides": {
    "semver": "^7.5.3"
  }
```

After adding this just run `npm i` on the terminal which will fix the issue.

Comment: TIL - Thanks for this it was what was required to fix our vulnerability. I have never used this section of the package.json file.
I will consider this a maintenance overhead and ensure we check if its still needed in our next audit and remove it if its no longer required.

Answer (score 3):

Looks like there are moderate vulnerabilities related to Semver.
I have the same props like you.

https://github.com/advisories/GHSA-c2qf-rxjj-qqgw

Semvr itself updated yesterday to 7.5.3:

[enter link description here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/semver)

Anyway. I found my issue due to the fact looking into the logs from the pipeline. So updating to targetversion 34 worked for me.

> Execution failed for task ':app:checkReleaseAarMetadata'.
> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.CheckAarMetadataWorkAction
> An issue was found when checking AAR metadata:

```
   1.  Dependency 'androidx.browser:browser:1.6.0-beta01' requires libraries and applications that

       depend on it to compile against version 34 or later of the

       Android APIs.

 

       :app is currently compiled against android-33.

 

       Also, the maximum recommended compile SDK version for Android Gradle

       plugin 7.3.1 is 33.

 

       Recommended action: Update this project's version of the Android Gradle

       plugin to one that supports 34, then update this project to use

       compileSdkVerion of at least 34.

 

       Note that updating a library or application's compileSdkVersion (which

       allows newer APIs to be used) can be done separately from updating

       targetSdkVersion (which opts the app in to new runtime behavior) and

       minSdkVersion (which determines which devices the app can be installed

       on).
```

(Note: I cannot add a comment yet due to less reputation :))

Answer (score 1):

I have solved it without adding it in my package.json

"overrides": {
"semver": "~7.5.3"
}

First, I cloned my GitHub repository and then checked the package-lock.json file. I discovered that semver was a dependency of the nodemon package in my case.
[image: nodemon's semver dependency]

To resolve the security vulnerability, I uninstalled nodemon and reinstalled it as a dev dependency. This simple action successfully fixed the security issue on GitHub.

If you are facing a similar problem, check your package-lock.json file and try to fix it using the same approach. I hope it will be fixed for you as well.

Comment: For future readers: what it fixed is not that he re-installed as dev dependencies, but rather that he re-installed. Doing so, the package was upgraded and the upgraded version of nodemon has the patch for the vulnerability in the semver dependencies. 

Also, it is general good practice to keep nodemon in the dev dependencies as we generally need it mostly for development, not production.

Comment: This solution may not work if the dependency (semver) version is not updated by the other package (nodemon) hence in such cases overrides will be required, see my solution for overrides.